# Meteor project: hyperlinks doesn't work always in twitter bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor project with a Twitter Bootstrap layout frame. In my templates I define a navbar as follow:

```
<template name="navbar">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <a class="brand" href="/about">Protocol Planner</a>
     <div class="navbar-content"</div>
      <ul class="nav pull-left">
       <li><a class="" id="plan_button" href="/protocol_plannen">Plannen</a></li>
       <li><a class="" id="pat_button" href="/protocol_viewing">Uitvoeren</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
       <li><a class="" id="admin_button" href="/admin"><i class="icon-wrench icon-white"></i></a></li>
       <li><a class="" id="logout_button" href="/"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i></a></li>
       <li><a class="" id="profile_btn" href="/profile"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> {{currentUser.profile.name}}</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

The following problems occurs. When the page is loaded, alle hyperlinks are clickable. However when you click the hyperlink "Uitvoeren", that page is loaded and you can't click the hyperlink "Plannen" anymore. Also the hyperlinks on the right side are unclickable in that case, except the link to the /profile page. Hen you then first click on the /about link, all links are clickable again.

I'm using the iron router.

Is there anyone who can help with this problem?

Kind regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot click"? Is it still clickable but the routing no longer works? Does the styling of the link changes?

Comment: The router works, but the mouse cursur doesn't change in a hand symbol. When you click on the link in the navbar, nothing happens. Even the link doesn't light up in the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some research I found what the problem was.

When I click the link "Uitvoeren" that page is loading. So, the template for the page "Uitvoeren" is rendered. In the template there are three modal templates defined:

```
<template name="Uitvoeren">
 ....
 {{> modal_1}}
 {{> modal_2}}
 {{> modal_3}}
</template>
```

The modal templates are defined as follow:

```
<template name="modal_1">
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
   <h3>myModal</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="button">OK</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

The problem was that, even the modals where not visible, They where displayed on top of the page, above the navbar. So the links on the navbar wheren't accessible because of the modals above them.

An extra peace of code in the definition of the modal templates is necessary to eliminate this problem:

```
<template name="modal_1">
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" style="display: none;">
 ....
</template>
```

Now it looks that everything works fine.

Kind regards.